# Proving an upper and lower bound for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, lower-bound

How can one proove an upper and lower bound for an algorithm?

Up until now, I thought both the upper and lower bound for an algorithm needs to be shown by taking into account *all* inputs and showing that it can not do worse than f(n) [upper bound] and not better than g(n) [lower bound].

My lecturer said that for the upper bound one needs to prove it in general [taking into accoung all inputs], but for a lower bound an example is sufficient.

This really confused me. 
Can anyone clarify what he meant?

Comment: Your lecturer is wrong - or you misunderstood him. If you want to show a best case performance of `g(n)` - you need to: (1) prove no input performs better than `g(n)`. (2) (If you want it to be strict) show some input with performance of `g(n)`, same as upper bound (but in the other direction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lecturer is right if he speaks of the worst-case behavior.

From a single example, you can say that the running time is "at least that much" (and can be worse), but not that it is "at most that much" (as it can be worse).

[Symmetrically, when speaking of the best-case behavior, a single case gives a guarantee on the upper bound.]

The lower and upper bounds are quite different things. The lower bound is usually established "universally", i.e. irrespective of any particular algorithm. For instance, you cannot sort a sequence in less than N.Log(N) comparisons in the worst case, as you need to distinguish among N! possible permutations, and that requires to gather Lg(N!) bits of information.

On the opposite, the upper bound is determined for a particular algorithm. For instance, HeapSort never exceeds 2N.Lg(N) comparisons. When the upper bound meets the lower bound, the algorithm is said to be efficient.

Comment: No, he's not. Take the example of a quicksort (with pivot as first element), and I give you an example of a sorted array. Is the "lower bound" (best case performance) Theta(n^2)?

Comment: Yes, Omega(N²) is a lower bound on the worst case.

Comment: I don't think that what he meant, I believe his "upper bound" and "lower bound" for an algorithm really means (poorly worded) best and worst case performance, and not O and Omega of worst case.

Comment: My answer is about lower and upper bounds of the worst-case behavior (best-case too, for completeness). Only with this interpretation does the quote from the lecturer make sense.

Comment: So the lower bound is equivalent to the best-case performance of an algorithm?

Comment: @XerXes: lower bound of which case, be specific ?

Comment: Your second sentence in the post does make sense and I think this is what he meant. If this is true and an example for the lower bound of the worst case of an algorithm is basically enough, why did we have to do it "universally" in the case of showing the lower bound of the worst case of sorting. Is it because in the later we are trying to figure out the lower bound of the worst case of a "problem" and in the former that of an "algorithm"?

Comment: @XerXes: you name it precisely: I spoke of a lower bound for a problem and an upper bound for an algorithm. A lower bound for an algorithm is of little interest as you want the algorithm to run fast (and not "as slowly as possible"). A lower bound for a problem is extremely interesting as it defines a goal to achieve: the algorithm worst-case upper bound reaching the problem worst-case lower bound. (Sometimes the average-case behavior is used instead.)